# AngularJS v1.8.0 ng-selected option not working

Tags: angularjs

I just updated the AngularJs version from  AngularJS v1.4.8 to  AngularJS v1.8.0 and I have a select which requires a default value. for some reason the ng-selected stop working. Can you please advise how to set the ng-selected on 1.8.0 please? (code uses an ng-model)

````
        <input  name="questionamount" class="form-control uservalue" type="number" min="0" ng-model="userInput1" ng-disabled="content.NotRelevant" ng-blur="setMainFieldAsTouched(); updateFormVisibility()" ng-change="update('userInput1',userInput1)" val-bubble>
        <select name="questionperiod" class="form-control" ng-model="userInput2" ng-disabled="content.NotRelevant" ng-blur="setMainFieldAsTouched()" ng-change="update('userInput2',userInput2)" val-bubble>
            <option value="">-- Select a period --</option>
            <option value="48">Year</option>
            <option value="24">6 Months</option>
            <option value="12">Quarter</option>
            <option value="4" ng-selected="true">Month</option>
            <option value="5">Four Weekly</option>
            <option value="2">2 Weeks</option>
            <option value="1">Week</option>
        </select>       
        <input name="questionvalue" class="form-control" type="number" min="0" readonly ng-required="content.Mandatory && !content.NotRelevant" max="{{content.TriggerLimit}}" ng-change="update('content.Value',content.Value)" ng-blur="updateFormVisibility()" ng-model="content.Value" val-bubble>  
    </div> ```

Thanks in advance,

Jordi
````

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected):

> Note: ngSelected does not interact with the select and ngModel
> directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you
> are using ngModel on the select, you should not use ngSelected on the
> options, as ngModel will set the select value and selected options.

Which would mean, set the value of userInput2 to your default value and do not use the `ng-selected` attribute. See also [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value).

Comment: So , sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. I'm not familiar with angular. What do you mean with setting the value of UserInput2 to the default value? Thanks

Comment: Set `userInput2 = 4` if 4 is your default value.